# Printing columns with two kinds of field separator awk

Tags: awk

I want to print the following file in a way that the first six columns are always separated by tab and the rest (it can be two or more) always by space.

For a sample file:

```
1   1   0   0   1   0   2   2   1   1
1   2   0   0   2   0   2   2   1   1
1   3   1   2   1   0   2   2   1   1
1   4   1   2   2   0   2   2   1   1
1   5   1   2   1   0   2   2   1   1
1   6   1   2   1   0   2   2   1   1
1   7   1   2   2   0   2   2   1   1
```

I achieve this by typing:

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7" "$8" "$9" "$10}' file
```

But instead of typing from column 7 onwards, I want to say the rest of the columns as the number of columns varies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for` to loop over the the fields.

```
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (i<7) {
            ORS="\t"
        } else if (i != NF) {
            ORS=" "
        } else {
            ORS="\n"
        }
        print $i
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
$ awk -f prog.awk file
1   1   0   0   1   0   2 2 1 1
1   2   0   0   2   0   2 2 1 1
1   3   1   2   1   0   2 2 1 1
1   4   1   2   2   0   2 2 1 1
1   5   1   2   1   0   2 2 1 1
1   6   1   2   1   0   2 2 1 1
1   7   1   2   2   0   2 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    r = $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $6 "\t";
    for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) {
        r = r $i " ";
    }
    print substr(r,1,length(r)-1)
}
```

You code works for a static number of fields.

The NF variable contains the total number of fields of the current record.
So you can use it in a for loop to dynamically concatenate fields.

Also, there is a remaining space at the end of the loop which is removed by substr.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

This is how to really do it:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1; for(i=1;i<=6;i++) sub(/ /,"\t")}1' file
1       1       0       0       1       0       2 2 1 1
1       2       0       0       2       0       2 2 1 1
1       3       1       2       1       0       2 2 1 1
1       4       1       2       2       0       2 2 1 1
1       5       1       2       1       0       2 2 1 1
1       6       1       2       1       0       2 2 1 1
1       7       1       2       2       0       2 2 1 1
```

`$1=$1` recompiles the current record replacing all sequences of contiguous white space (FS) with a single blank char (OFS), the `sub()` simply replaces the first blank on the line with a tab, and the loop repeats that `sub()` 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

with GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/ +/\t/g; s/\t/ /7g' file

1       1       0       0       1       0       2 2 1 1
1       2       0       0       2       0       2 2 1 1
1       3       1       2       1       0       2 2 1 1
1       4       1       2       2       0       2 2 1 1
1       5       1       2       1       0       2 2 1 1
1       6       1       2       1       0       2 2 1 1
1       7       1       2       2       0       2 2 1 1
```

first convert field separator to tab, then change to space from 7th to end.  If the fields are already tab delimited you can skip the first statement.